# Java Interface - Auto-generate method implementation (optionally limited to Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, code-generation

I have an interface defined as:

```
public interface IDomainEntity {
    /**
     * @return
     *   A serialized form of the class Object.
     *   Follows the format:<br/><br/>
     *   <pre class="brush: java">
     *   {@code
     *  public String getPropertiesString() {
     *      String resultString = new StringBuilder()
     *          .append( String.valueOf(this.getClass().getSimpleName()) + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode()) + " {" )
     *          .append( " ${property}: '" + String.valueOf(this.${property}) + "'," )
     *          //... above line repeated N-1 times for N properties (${property})...
     *          .append( " }" );
     *          .toString();
     *      
     *      resultString = resultString.replace(", }", " }");
     *      return resultString;
     *  }
     *   </pre>
     */
    public String getPropertiesString();
}
```

Is there something I can do to cause `Eclipse` to `auto-generate` the contents of the method to what I have in my `javadoc` comment, expanding all direct properties for the class (I don't care about `parent` properties for `inheritance`).

Currently, Eclipse will give me:

```
@Override
public String getPropertiesString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

From `Java Code Style` >> `Code Templates` >> `Code` >> `Method body` (JDT), but I'm looking for something specific to 1 `interface` and the resulting `domain class` that `implements` it.

Fyi, I am hoping to avoid any solutions revolving around using `aspects` or `reflection` to get all of the properties for the class.

Thanks!

Comment: ...isn't the entire point of an interface/abstract method that the implementing class can implement it any way they want?

Comment: @Powerlord: generally that is true, however, since this is a private application for our team here, we control all the implementations of each interface. I'm not saying that an implementation must end up having 100% the same code as the `javadoc` example, but I wanted to see if there was a way to pre-generate the implementation (which can then be modified if slightly different output is desired), I figure it'll probably have to be IDE specific, but I don't know because I have yet to see a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you could add a default implementation to your interface

Comment: I am using JDK 8, but I don't see how I can add a default for this, because I don't know all of the properties of the class that is implementing the interface. I was kinda hoping code generation would handle it for me.